# Url/Link validation

Tags: office-ui-fabric

Is there a way for link/url validation in Fabric when a user inputs some value in a TextField without Regex?

```
  public render(): JSX.Element {
    // tslint:disable:jsx-no-lambda
    return (
      <div style={{ padding: '2px' }}>

        <TextField          
          label="Url"          
          onGetErrorMessage={this._checkIfValid}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }

  private _checkIfValid(value: string) {    
    alert("Test");
  }
```

Link to codepen: https://codepen.io/lipalath/pen/oRaYvJ?editors=1111

Comment: Would Regex.test not solve your issue here? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expressions should help you validate for URLs.

```js
  public render(): JSX.Element {
    // tslint:disable:jsx-no-lambda
    return (
      <div style={{ padding: '2px' }}>

        <TextField          
          label="Url"          
          onGetErrorMessage={this._checkIfValid}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }

  private _checkIfValid(value: string) {    
    const regex = new Regexp(/^(?:http(s)?:\/\/)?[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w\.-]+)+[\w\-\._~:/?#[\]@!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=.]+$/, 'g');
    return regex.test(value);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to validate without Regex in Fabric?